# How to let a cell blink for a configurable time in wx.grid when the value changes?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using a wx.grid in Python to display stock prices. After the value of a cell changes, I want to change the background and font color for a short period, say 0.5 seconds and then change it back to its original colors. If I do this in a straightforward way, I just change both colors, do a time.sleep(0.5) and change it back to its original colors. However, this way the update per cell takes way too long. Does anybody know of a clever way to do this?

Comment: Are you doing this in the same thread? Just do the "change colors" code in a separate thread.

Comment: I have thought of using another thread and probably this is the right thing to do. But I already use quite a few threads so I tried to avoid this and so was curious if other solutions are available

Comment: There's really no way around it. You want the application to do things concurrently. You _have_ to use a separate thread. Fortunately, though, threads have a relatively low memory overhead, so using "too many threads" should not be an issue. If you are really concerned however, you could make all color changes occur within the same thread, or within a limited number of threads.

Comment: The separate thread was indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Change the color and use wxTimerEvent to set the delay until you change it back in the event handler.